# Why is the map frame suddenly empty in QGIS-print composer?

Tags: qgis, print-composer

Often when working in QGIS  print-composer (2.14 and prior), at a certain point the map content disappears and only the empty map frame remains. This happens mostly after closing and re-opening my project or randomly after I hit the "refresh preview" button.

My solution so far was to just add new mapframes (over and over again) but this is annoying.

What is the reason behind my map-preview disappearing and what to do about it? The screenshot shows the problem and the general adjustment I am using.

[image: screenshot_frame]

Comment: maybe you can try it again, but this time check the option to lock the map layer (kartenelements Layer festhalten)..

Comment: Have you tried just pressing the "Vorschau aktualisieren" button?

Comment: @UjeIndo thanks maybe that will help! I'll post an update how it worked.

Comment: @underdark - yep, I tried that. :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the reason to be the CRS settings: The project settings are "On The Fly - Transformation" to an UTM projection of my choice. I've realised that somehow QGIS changes the CRS setting from my UTM-Zone to WGS84 after saving, closing and re-opening - don't ask why.
Of course, after the setting is changed to WGS84, the area is not displayed correctly in the mapframe anymore. By simply choosing the correct CRS in the 'properties' -> 'CRS' menu again, the map is correctly displayed in the print composer.